# Seq.where with Seq.groupBy

Tags: f#

In learning F# I am doing a small challenge:

> Enter a string and the program counts the number of vowels in the text. For added complexity have it report a sum of each vowel found.

This is what I have so far:

```
let rec Main = 
    let vowels = [| 'a'; 'e'; 'i'; 'o'; 'u'|]
    let charIsVowel char = Seq.exists ((=) char) vowels

    let inputText = Console.ReadLine()

    let expression = 
        inputText
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun char -> char)
        |> Seq.where charIsVowel
```

The problem is that I cannot access the key of the grouping which is a `char` and so I cannot filter the sequence. 
The specific error is:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       char * seq -> bool
>   but given a
>       char -> bool
>   The type 'char * seq' does not match the type 'char'

Ultimately, I want to filter a sequence of gropings according to their key. How can I do this?

Comment: A more efficient way to check for vowelness: `let vowels = set [ 'a'; 'e'; 'i'; 'o'; 'u' ]; let charIsVowel c = vowels.Contains c`  Or, indeed, simply `let charIsVowel = vowels.Contains`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to take the tuple apart first before calling `charIsVowel`:

```
Seq.where (fun (char, s) -> charIsVowel char)
```

An alternative is to use the `fst` function along with function composition:

```
Seq.where (fst >> charIsVowel)
```

The `fst` function turns `(char, s)` into `char` and then the `>>` operator passes the result into `charIsVowel`.

Note that your `(fun char -> char)` in the `groupBy` can be expressed simply as the *identity* function `id`:

```
Seq.groupBy id
```

Comment: This is the final result I came up with: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e0ec67e372f52cc96f7 Any other suggestions?

Comment: @CasterTroy Personally, to match the semantics you're after, I'd change `vowels` to a set: `let vowels = set(['a';'e'])` etc, and then do `let isVowel c = vowels |> Set.contains c`. Incidentally, it also will be more performant during the lookup, which won't matter at all in this case. Otherwise, looks good from my POV. :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek or indeed `let isVowel = vowels.Contains`

Comment: @phoog Absolutely, I somehow missed that option when typing the comment inline... :)